# Delete Confirmation with Bootstrap

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have following page to confirm the deletion of  table item by using bootstrap modal. When I click delete button, I can not see the modal div. What's my wrong?

```
<?php
    $content = [0=>["news_id"=>1,"news_title"=>"Hürriyet","news_date"=>"Bugün","news_content"=>"siyaset"],
                1=>["news_id"=>2,"news_title"=>"Milliyet","news_date"=>"Yarın","news_content"=>"ekonomi"],
                2=>["news_id"=>3,"news_title"=>"Sabah","news_date"=>"Dün","news_content"=>"politika"]]
  ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".btn-show-modal").click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
  var modal_id = "dialog-example_"+id; 
  $("#"+modal_id).modal('show');
});

$(".btn btn-danger").click(function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var modal_id = "dialog-example_"+id;
  $("#"+modal_id).modal('hide');
});

});
</script>

    <div class="container">

          <!-- Modal -->
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="60">ID</th>
                    <th width="200">Title</th>
                    <th width="150">Date Posted</th>
                    <th>Content</th>
                    <th width="200">Image</th>
                    <th width="200">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php

            foreach ($content as $row) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_title']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_date']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_content']; ?></td>
                    <td><img style="height:50px; width:50px;" src=""  ></td>
                    <td>
                         <a href="edit2.php?newsid=<?php echo $row['news_id'];?>" class='btn btn-info left-margin'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a>
                         <a href="#<?php $row['news_id'] ?>" id="<?php echo $row['news_id'] ?>" data-id="<?php echo $row['news_id'] ?>" class='btn-show-modal' data-toggle="modal" title="Delede Record"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</a>
                    </td>
                <div class="modal hide fade" id="dialog-example_<?php echo $row['news_id'] ?>">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5>Confirm Delete</h5>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <p class="modaltext">Are you sure you want to delete this record?</p>
                      </div>    
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info">No</a>
                        <a href="delete-project.php?code=<?php echo $row['news_id']; ?>" 
                          class="btn btn-danger" id="<?php echo $row['news_id'] ;?>">Yes</a>
                      </div>
                </div>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Because of this I can not see whether my code is running.

Comment: You should try to load bootstrap and jquery before script tag.

Comment: I think, I already loaded them before script tag.

Comment: Try to see `modal_id` in console. Is it ok?

Comment: Yesi, it's ok. I can see. They are before table in console?

Comment: replace `$(this).attr('id')` with `$(e).attr('id')`

Comment: No I mean add this `console.log(modal_id);` before `$("#"+modal_id).modal('hide');`

Comment: when I repalace $(this).attr('id') with $(e).attr('id') I can not see anything. In my code I can see gray transparent modal screen but can not see modal div.

Comment: If you have possibility, can you run my code on your local?

Comment: Ok, I found mistakes.. I have some problems about, modal classes. I deleted hide class from modal and added modal-dialog and modal-content divs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working code!**

I rewrote your modal and changed the way it opens to onclick="" functions for the button elements.

```php
    <?php
    $content = [0=>["news_id"=>1,"news_title"=>"Hürriyet","news_date"=>"Bugün","news_content"=>"siyaset"],
    1=>["news_id"=>2,"news_title"=>"Milliyet","news_date"=>"Yarın","news_content"=>"ekonomi"],
    2=>["news_id"=>3,"news_title"=>"Sabah","news_date"=>"Dün","news_content"=>"politika"]]
    ?>
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
    
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
    
      <body>
    
        <div class="container">
    
          <!-- Modal -->
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th width="60">ID</th>
                <th width="200">Title</th>
                <th width="150">Date Posted</th>
                <th>Content</th>
                <th width="200">Image</th>
                <th width="200">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
    
    foreach ($content as $row) {
        ?>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?php echo $row['news_id']; ?>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <?php echo $row['news_title']; ?>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <?php echo $row['news_date']; ?>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <?php echo $row['news_content']; ?>
                  </td>
                  <td><img style="height:50px; width:50px;" src=""></td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="edit2.php?newsid=<?php echo $row['news_id'];?>" class='btn btn-info left-margin'>
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">Edit</span>
                    </a>
    
                    <a onclick="$('#dialog-example_<?php echo $row['news_id'] ?>').modal('show');" href="#" class='btn-show-modal' data-toggle="modal" title="Delede Record">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete
                    </a>
                  </td>
    
                  <div id="dialog-example_<?php echo $row['news_id'] ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
                      <!-- Modal content-->
                      <div class="modal-content" id="dialog-example_<?php echo $row['news_id'] ?>">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <p>Are you sure you want to delete this record?</p>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->
                          <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info" onclick="$('#dialog-example_<?php echo $row['news_id'] ?>').modal('hide');">No</a>
                          <a href="delete-project.php?code=<?php echo $row['news_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" id="<?php echo $row['news_id'] ;?>">Yes</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
    
                    </div>
                  </div>
    
                </tr>
                <?php
    }
    ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </body>
    
      </html>
```

Comment: You may want to change the bootstrap js and css urls back to your own :)

Comment: Ok, thank you.;) Next step, How Can i  send item id to delete-project.php page by using post method. )

Comment: Check the console, it's because /delete-project.php does not exist. Just correct it to an existing php page

Comment: I get "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #" this erron in console.

Comment: Actually I get this error with working code, it's different error probably. I added existing page but same result. Doing nothing.

Comment: @YusufÇAKIRCA Take a look at AJAX requests here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp if you want the user to stay on the same page while still deleting the report. Other wise you can make the "Yes" button a form and post it when the user clicks yes. This will redirect the user to the page which will delete the report.

Comment: Thanks for your help.